# When does C++11 give warnings about operator precedence?

Tags: c++11, gcc, parentheses, operator-precedence, suppress-warnings

When writing code, for a long time I knew that && has higher precedence than ||; however, compiling it using the C++11 standard gave me a warning that I should now use parentheses when using both in a single statement.

Now I got a warning that combining >> and + also should have parentheses.  Now my statements look really ugly, with 5 or more parentheses floating around them.

1) Is there a resource that says which combinations of operators now require parentheses?

2) Is there a way to silence just the operator precedence warnings, but to keep the other warnings?

Compiler `gcc` with flags `-O2 -Wall -g`

The warnings came in when I added the flag `-std=c++11`

Sample expression:

```
(((string[0] << CHAR_BIT) + string[1] << CHAR_BIT) + string[2] << CHAR_BIT) + string[3];
```

Comment: The standard doesn't say that any warnings must be emitted (though it may recommend to do so). They're emitted by the compilers as a help to you and thus disabling them is compiler-specific

Comment: Which compiler? You should add it to the tags.

Comment: Post the expressions in question. A warning is rarely emitted without cause.

Comment: @tambre: As far as I know, the language (i..e, the standard document) makes no recommendations about warnings for operator precedence.

Comment: I thought that compilers are a tool - and therefore should be helpful as possible. Giving warnings is a way of preventing potential errors. Treat them as errors and you will not go far wrong

Comment: @KeithThompson The C++14 Standard I'm looking at definitely recommends the implementation issue a warning on multiple occasions.

Comment: I would recommend always using parentheses to be explicit.

Comment: "Now my statements look really ugly, with 5 or more parentheses floating around them." -- you can decompose this statement to restore beauty.

Comment: @cdhowie But this would not be equivalent.  I would have to shift `string[0] << 3*CHAR_BIT` instead; etc.-- which would be less efficient on the assembly level.

Comment: @Alex: That expression should be in a function somewhere, with a name that tells people exactly what it's supposed to do. At which point, the number of necessary parenthesis is no longer an issue.

Comment: @Alex Right, I missed that. But is `CHAR_BIT` a constant value available at compile time, as the naming implies? If so, the compiler would just fold the multiplication operation at compile time.

Comment: @cdhowie Good point.  That will work for this expression; maybe I should post another one with tons of parentheses. :)

Comment: @Alex Maybe you should decompose complex expressions into several easier-to-understand statements instead of trying to pack as much as you can into one line.

Comment: @DeiDei: Interesting. Can you cite an example of such a recommendation? I haven't found any in the N4296 draft, which as I understand it is pretty close to C++14, but my search wasn't thorough. (I'm specifically asking about recommendations for warnings involving operator precedence.) (Amusingly, a search for "recommend" turned up a note in [atomics.order] 29.3 referring to `r1 == r2 == 42`, which should have been written as `r1 == 42 && r2 == 42`.)

Comment: @KeithThompson I just did a search for "warning". The keyword is actually "encourage" rather than "recommend" though. Looking at the C++1z draft, most of the references are regarding some attributes (maybe_unusued, fallthrough, etc) and dangling references/pointers. Nothing about operator precedence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html):

> -Wparentheses
>
> Warn if parentheses are omitted in certain contexts, such as when there is an assignment in a context where a truth value is expected,
>   **or when operators are nested whose precedence people often get
>   confused about.**
>
> Also warn if a comparison like x<=y<=z appears; this is equivalent to (x<=y ? 1 : 0) <= z, which is a different interpretation from that
>   of ordinary mathematical notation.
>
> Also warn for dangerous uses of the GNU extension to ?: with omitted middle operand. When the condition in the ?: operator is a
>   boolean expression, the omitted value is always 1. Often programmers
>   expect it to be a value computed inside the conditional expression
>   instead.

(I added the emphasis)

To turn this behavior off, specify `-Wno-parentheses` to `gcc/g++`.

Comment: Thanks-- this overrides the `-std=c++11` option, which was what I was aiming for.

Comment: @Alex: No, it doesn't override `-std=c++11`. It merely causes the compiler to issue some extra warnings, which are permitted by the standard. (The standard requires diagnostics for some things, but permits additional warnings for anything the compiler wants to warn about. I know C is defined that way; I'm pretty sure C++ is too.)

Answer (score 3):

> When does C++11 give warnings about operator precedence?

The only case when the standard requires a diagnostic message (note that the standard does not distinguish between warnings and errors that halt the compilation) is when the program violates the standard. Except when the compiler is excempt from that with wording "no diagnostic required".

All other warnings are optional for the compiler and not required by the standard.

---

> 1) Is there a resource that says which combinations of operators now require parentheses?

No, because the parentheses are not required. The warning is just a suggestion by the compiler. The program is well-formed.

> The warnings came in when I added the flag -std=c++11

For what it's worth, my GCC warns regardless of the standard argument.

---

> 2) Is there a way to silence just the operator precedence warnings, but to keep the other warnings?

The warning itself tells which warning option has enabled it (here is the warning from my GCC):

> warning: suggest parentheses around '+' inside '<<' **[-Wparentheses]**

To disable, you can use the corresponding option to disable it: `-Wno-WHATEVER`.

---

> Now my statements look really ugly, with 5 or more parentheses floating around them.

I recommend instead to extract the repetitive structure, and reuse a standard algorithm:

```
std::accumulate(string, string + 4, 0, [](auto sum, auto value) {
    return (sum << CHAR_BIT) + value;
});
```

Much fewer parentheses :) Note that in C++11 (prior to C++14) you can not use `auto` as the type of an argument of a lambda. I don't know what types you use.

Comment: I get `operator "<<" has lower precedence than "+"; "+" will be
      evaluated first [-Wshift-op-parentheses]`; I don't think this one can be figured out how to disable as easily as when `[-Wparentheses]` is part of the warning.

Comment: Wow, it does.  Never knew that, thanks!  Too bad I already accepted dlasalle's answer...

Comment: @Alex see my suggestion for rewriting the expression. I didn't bother testing so make sure it has the same behaviour as you need.